# Does Android Mobile display the LogCat output or it just display what emulator displays

Tags: android, android-emulator, emulation

My question is, when we use Log.d(), Log.v(). Are these visible on android screen as output or do they just remain in the background and Android Mobile just display what the emulator displays in Computer?

Answer (score 2):

Logging is just something, that enables developers the possibility to check if his code is working like it's intended to be, the user won't see any of the log statements. But it's recommended to remove all logs before publishing your App:

> Turn off logging and debugging
>
> Make sure you deactivate logging and disable the debugging option
>   before you build your application for release. You can deactivate
>   logging by removing calls to Log methods in your source files. You can
>   disable debugging by removing the android:debuggable attribute from
>   the  tag in your manifest file, or by setting the
>   android:debuggable attribute to false in your manifest file. Also,
>   remove any log files or static test files that were created in your
>   project.

Source [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/preparing.html).

Answer (score 1):

No, this is purely a background thing, viewable with the LogCat view in Eclipse. The user will not see anything Log related, they will be oblivious to it while using the app. 
So yes, it will display what your emulator displays. Of course if you need them to see something, you can show Toasts and Dialogs. However, make sure to take out Log statements in release versions of your app. People that have debugging enabled will be able to see your statements if they attach their phone to a computer and run LogCat.

Comment: Thanks,....  Then how can I display the database data on emulator??? I have gotten it in a list and was using Log mechanism to display it